# php issue in using explode

Tags: php, explode

I have this code :

http://jsfiddle.net/S4rD9/

(i know the preview is messed up, it's just to show you the PHP code part I have)

Basicly, this is connected to my databse, and it takes the informations inside the text fields of each columns.
As you can see in the code, elements are fetched like this :

```
$row['img2']
```

Means it displays the information in the text field of the "img2" column.
The "img2" column has image path in it.

The part of the code that I'm having trouble with looks like this :

```
<div id="slides" class="col-md-7" >
 <img src="'.$row['img2'].'" >
  </div>
```

And I need it to use the "explode" function (I think that's the one I need to use), to get each values in that img2 column textbox in the database, seperated by a comma.
Right now in the database, the text field of the first row (for example) of the img2 column is :

img/img-araignee-big.jpg, img/img-bug-big.jpg

But it only gets the "img/img-araignee-big.jpg" part.

Someone sent me this :

```
  <div id="slides" class="col-md-7" >
  <?php
  $images = explode(',', $row['img2']);
  foreach($images as $image) {
  ?>
  <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" >
  <?php } ?>
   </div>
```

He said it should work, but I cannot get this to work correctly.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are storing multiple paths in the same column? That's not generally the best way to go about things.

Comment: alright,i l think abt doing it another way,but as of now,can u suggest any solution for my problem

Comment: "but I cannot get this to work correctly"… So what _is_ happening? Are you getting an error? If so, what? If not, what does the output/result look like?

Comment: `explode(', ', $row['img2']);` just add a space after the comma

Comment: @CodeBird it is not required, he is doing some other mistake

Comment: that was my answer on the previous question you made, it should work with your result, also the space doesn't really matter because of how the src attribute works, post the result that isn't working so we can help futher

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="slides" class="col-md-7" >
  <?php
  $images = explode(',', $row['img2']);
  foreach($images as $image) {
      print '<img src="' . $image . '">';
  } ?>
</div>
```